# Port Cordova plugin(database API) to Node.Js module?

Tags: node.js, cordova, couchbase, couchbase-lite, jxcore

I am using Couchbase products as a database to develop a suite of applications (mobile, web, desktop) with offline capability. Our app will be a Html + Css + Javascript that should be cross platform. Angular and PhoneGap also used for being able to use a MVC pattern and build for mobile.

We want to also use JxCore (Node.Js fork) as a separate back-end service that would talk with the Couchbase Server or Couchbase Lite depending on the type of the app. (WebApp would talk directly with the Couchbase Server hosted on a cluster and apps that are deployed on client devices will need to talk to Couchbase Lite(embedded) and sync with the Couchbase Server.

Currently Couchbase offers a SDK for Node.Js to talk to the Couchbase Server, but not something similar for Couchbase Lite. PhoneGap on the other side, has a plugin for Couchbase Lite but like I said before we would prefer a backend node.js that will talk with the database and expose a rest API which will be called by the client apps to work with the data in the database.

Is there any possibility I can adapt this Couchbase Lite plugin so I can use it with Node.js (don't worry that this plugin dont have any desktop platform, we can solve this).

Link to the Couchbase Lite Plugin:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin

Link to JxCore Plugin we use:
https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova

I don't know if this is doable, I am a dummy working with those technologies.
Please let me know if I need to clarify something, thanks!

Comment: jxcore mobile has leveldown mobile is embedded. Why don't you use pouchdb ?

Comment: well I ended using PouchDB.. I was a little afraid of compatibility problems with Sync Gateway